# django url error this problem is happening only when user is logged in

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku

```
"Environment of the project:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: 

Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Version: 3.10.7"
"error is with the template and url"
"eg: more details about question ....................................."
"error at line 12"
   "Reverse for 'customer' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customer/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']"
   2 : 
   3 : <div class="homeWrapper">
   4 :         <header>
   5 :             <nav>
   6 :                 <ul class="nav__links">
   7 :                     <li><a href="{% url 'home'  %}">Home</a></li>
   8 :                     <li><a href="{% url 'gallery'  %}">Gallery</a></li>
   9 :                     <li><a href="#faqs" class="scroll">About us</a></li>
   10 :                     <!--page is in demo mode after deployment logic will be made here-->
```

##error is with line 12

```
   11 :                     {% if user.is_authenticated  %}
   12 :                         <li><a href=" {% url 'customer' pk=current.id %} ">Customer</a></li>
   13 :                     {% else  %}
   14 :                         <li><a class="scroll" href="#login">Login</a></li>
   15 :                     {% endif %}
   16 :                     {% if request.user.is_staff  %}
   17 :                         <li><a href="{% url 'graph'  %}">Dash Board</a></li>
   18 :                     {%endif%}
   19 :                     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/darkmode-js@1.5.7/lib/darkmode-js.min.js"></script>
   20 :                 </ul>
   21 :             </nav>
   22 :
```

#log
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/app/website/views.py", line 298, in gallery
return render ( request, 'gallery.html', context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
return template.render(context, request)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
return self.template.render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
return self._render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
return template.render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 173, in render
return self._render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
return nodelist.render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /gallery
Exception Value: Reverse for 'customer' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customer/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']
```

"
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MqOm.jpg

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pk=user.id` and not `pk=current.id` in the url tag?

Comment: share your url patters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

====== put like this =====

```
{% url 'customer' request.user.id %}
```